# Get values from list inside dictionary and save it in a list of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary A containing day as a key, and list of strings as a values example:

```
A = {"day1": ['A', 'B', 'C']}.
```

How can I create a List B containing the unique relationships that will be established Lists?

```
B = [['A','B'], ['A','C'], ['B','C']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = {"day1": ['A', 'B', 'C']}
B = [['A','B'], ['A','C'], ['B','C']]

vals = A['day1']
connections = []
for val in vals:
    connections_to_val = [(val, x) for x in vals 
        if (val != x and (x, val) not in connections)]
    connections.extend(connections_to_val)
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but I didn't understand how connections_to_val works can you simplify it to separated for and if statements

Comment: connections_to_val is a list comprehension that basically loops through the values in vals = ('A', 'B', 'C') using the variable x and for every value it appends the tuple (val, x). So we append the tuple (val, x) if the conditions (val!=x and x,val not in connections) is true. That means that we don not want to append tuples where val and x are equal (i.e. ('A', 'A') and tuples that are already in the list but in opposite order (i.e. if ('A', 'B') is in there, do not append ('B', 'A').

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> A = {"day1": ['A', 'B', 'C']}
>>> seq = A["day1"]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(seq, r=2))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
```

Comment: the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations